# Python virtual environments broken with upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, using the prompts and GUI windows with the Ubuntu software updater to complete the upgrade.

Previous to the upgrade I had multiple virtual environments (`virtualenv`), each with an extensive set of Python packages installed.

When I activate a `virtualenv` any Python commands or `import` statements result in `ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref`. For example, `pip freeze` results in:

```
$ pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pwright/virtualenvs/btac-web-plots/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/pwright/virtualenvs/btac-web-plots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Same error for trying to start an `ipython` session:

```
$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pwright/virtualenvs/btac-web-plots/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/pwright/virtualenvs/btac-web-plots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/pwright/virtualenvs/btac-web-plots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Most of my virtual environments have Python 2.7.12, whereas my system Python is 2.7.15.

Has anyone else encountered this? What is this particular error, and what is my best solution for regaining the functionality of my virtual environments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+_remove_dead_weakref

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was resolved by creating new virtual environments. When creating a new `virtualenv` the installed Python is 2.7.15, which was likely the problem previously.

After creating new virtual environments and installing all packages with `pip`, my project-specific scripts run successfully. This is easy if you have a `requirements.txt` file, and much more tedious if not! I highly recommend creating a `requirements.txt` for each `virtualenv` prior to an Ubuntu upgrade.

Comment: for future reference, you can delete the virtual environment by deleting the folder. ex: `sudo rm -rf venv`